# Spring Framework - How to change locale in controller

Tags: spring-mvc, localization

I am new to Spring, and currently confusing about localization.
I'm using the following code to get text from messages_jp.properties file.

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages" />
</bean>
```

And now I want to switch to text from messages_en.properties file, is there any ways to change locale in controller within if...else... block, not with using url params like "?lang=en", something like:

```
if (user.getLang() == 1) {
    // set locale to en
} else {
    // set locale to jp
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you are trying to test the language integration, you can change the language in the browser and refresh the page (locale is set from the browser), alternatively you can use `Locale.setDefault(preferredLocale)`, in your controller. IMHO changing the browser setting is the best solution.

Comment: Check spring web's `LocaleResolver` [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/LocaleResolver.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to change language based on user's info in database, so change the language in the browser is not the point. Using Locale.setDefault() did not work too :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
<util:properties id="yourFileNameId" location="classpath:/yourFileName.properties"/>
```

In Controller

```
@Value("#{yourFileNameId['message_id']?:1}")
private int smalltext;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't understand this, how does it help me change display language?